# How to create Windows executable (.exe) from red lang?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, rebol2, red

I'm building a red lang application. How to create Windows executable (.exe) from red lang???

Comment: Perhaps you just should read the github Readme, it is explained with all details needed. So this is asking for the sake of asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already the red executable, you call from the command line

```
red -c -t Windows yourprogram.red
```

and you will get **yourprogram.exe** as a Windows program

[README.md](https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/README.md)

Of course I assume, you have also downloaded all the possibly additionally needed source files from either [red-lang/download](http://www.red-lang.org/p/download.html) or [github/red/red](https://github.com/red/red)

If you have a recent rebol interpreter, you can compile with

```
do/args %red.r "-t Windows yourprogram.red"
```

or use an available GUI shell for the red compiler e.g [redcompiler](http://www.rebol.org/download-a-script.r?script-name=redcompiler.r)